# Shortest Path in Graph, when it is obligatory to jump over every second edge

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I`ve been preparing myself for programming competition and I stumbled upon this problem, in which I have to find shortest path from source to destination in weighted and undirected graph, but I have to skip every second edge (so its weight is not important). Weight in graph are positive integers.

Original statement:

> Clara and Jake are on trip. They are driving in turns and car driver is being changed after every city. Find shortest path from source to destination, that Clara drove least miles. Write who should be car driver first.

What is the best approach to solve this problem? Is there any modification of any algorithm to solve it easy?

Edit: jumped edges has weight equal to 0, if edge can be skipped or not I have to check both options.

Comment: What does "*skip every second edge*" mean? Every second edge on the (yet unknown) shortest path? Or every second edge on the relaxation step. But then, it would depend on the order you relax edges and the algorithm you use. And what's wrong with just taking any Dijkstra variant (Dijkstra, A*, ALT, Arc Flags, ...) and then skipping the relaxation of every second edge? At the moment the requirement doesn't make much sense to me, what if an algorithm with heavy pre-computation that changes the relaxation order extremely, like Contraction Hierarchies is used? You need to elaborate on that.

Comment: I see, it is quite obvious. I meant that if we reached current vertex by foot ( reaching it wasn`t costless) now we can jump over the next edge to the adjacent vertex (so it is costless). You are right, relaxation on every second edge should work properly, I made mistake while solving this problem on paper and it created non-existent problems ,thanks ;)

Comment: So you mean that the edge weight is `0` (has no cost)? Which is fine for most algorithms, including Dijkstra variants. But again, which edges are affected? It clearly would heavily depend on the order of how the algorithm processes the edges. Which means that if you use a different order/algorithm, the resulting shortest path could be a different one. Which is unsound. So again, I don't get the requirement if you are not fixed to a specific algorithm.

Comment: Take a look at the following [image](https://i.imgur.com/cJULT8v.png). Red are the edges that are not "second edge". Blue are the "second edges" edges. However, the green one could be both, depending on the order of how you relax. So, what do you want? Should it be blue or red? It's unsound.

Comment: I want to check both options, option, when it is blue, and later when it is red

Comment: Please provide a link to the original statement. As described here it doesn't really make sense. It will also help validate an answer using the online judge (if any)

Comment: @Okabe But then it's necessary to following each path in the graph. And you can't stop the algorithm once you settled the destination because you don't know if there is another path which will set edge-weight to `0` for an edge that had high-cost for the current shortest-path candidate. Which means you must settle the whole graph (or at least every node that reaches the destination).

Comment: Original statement is not in english, unfortunetly, and my mate gave me that problem to solve before competition ;) @Zabuza so what is the problem? If there is edge which can have weight 0 or its original weight it depends on path we have chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to find the shortest path in a weighted graph with the additional complexity that the weight of a path is the sum of the weight of the odd edges (1, 3, ...) *or* the even edges (2, 4, ...) along the path.

You can do this by first creating a new graph:

1. for each vertex `v` in the original graph, create two vertices in the new graph, one will be called `even v` and the other one `odd v`
2. if `(u, v)` is an edge of weight `w` in the original graph, add the following edges to the new graph: `(even u, odd v)` with weight `w` and `(odd u, even v)` with weight `0`

Then do two usual Dijkstra to find the shortest path reaching `odd destination` and `even destination` from `even source`. The one with the smallest weight is the shortest path if Clara is first to drive.

Do the same procedure, starting from `odd source` to find the shortest path if Clara is driving second.

**Proof**

The invariant we want to have in the new graph is:

- `even v` is a vertex reached through a path whose last edge is even numbered
- `odd v` is a vertex reached through a path whose last edge is odd numbered

As we only add edges from `even` to `odd` and from `odd` to `even` this invariant is true for the whole new graph. We use a weight of `0` for even numbered edges to accomodate the special weighting function for paths.

The `source` in the original graph maps to the `even source` in the new graph has it is reached by a path containing `0` edges if Clara drive firsts. When Clara drives second, `source` maps to `odd source`.

`destination` in the original graph may map to either `even destination` or `odd destination` depending on the number of edges on the path. By taking the shortest weighted path to either we are sure to find the shortest path using the special weighting function in the original graph.

Comment: The original statement is: "Clara and Jake are on trip. They are driving in turns and car driver is being changed after every city. Find shortest path from source to destination, that Clara drove least miles. Write who should be car driver first. " It is not precise content ;)

Comment: @Okabe Thanks, ... Wait it changes the statement. Because now it may be the odd *or* even edges that have 0 weight...

Comment: I skipped it, because it is symmetrical, If it is known how to do it starting from even vertex it is symmetrical when starting from odd ;) I just wanted to find out how to solve the problem for any situation

Answer (score 4):

For every pair of adjacent edges insert pair of directed edges as on the picture, here i assume that first edge in every pair isn't counted.

[image]

Now you need to find shortest path in directed graph but not to destination vertex, instead find shortest paths to the destination vertex and to all vertices at distance 1 from the destination vertex and now you can easily deduce the shortest path length.

Comment: How does this address the issue with OP wanting to manipulate the edge weight of "*every second edge*" to `0`? Also, how does it prevent problems like [seen here](https://i.imgur.com/cJULT8v.png) where the order or relaxation clearly changes which edges are considered as "*second edge*". The description is still unclear at the moment and the problem is unsound.

Comment: @Zabura I believe OP talking about second edge in any path, so for every path the set of such edge is different. The same edge can be counted or not depending on path you choose.

Comment: Yes, I have to check all of possible paths in that problem. But what if there is a cycle a-b, b-c, c-d, d-a, so we count cost from a to c through 2 possible paths, do we take less cost then?

Comment: In a regular problem description a cycle can never lead to a shorter path. However, in your problem it can and will. If the cycle is of odd edge-length it will change the *"which edges are considered second edges"*, i.e. other edges get `0`. Thus, you need to track at least one iteration of an odd cycle.

Comment: @Okabe in this specific case you in corresponding directed graph you have edges ac1 with weight of a-b and edge ac2 with weight a-c. one of them is your answer.

Comment: @Zabuza i'm assuming that all weights are positive. And we are talking about every second edge on path, not on graph.

Comment: @Zabuza, off course it will change that fact, I am aware of that, sorry I haven`t clarified it earlier. If there were not any cycle I think it would be easy to done using DFS traversal. @Yola so then we take minimum of them? OK, so whole task is to use Dijkstra Algorithm on that new directed graph? ;)

Comment: @Zabuza, sorry, there is only one mode. You always step over original two edges in the modified graph.

Comment: @Okabe yes, you need to run any algorithm on new graph.

Comment: This will be very slow in a highly connected graph.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for your input, I agree with it, in a complete graph it is a nightmare. For a complete graph with `n` vertices, which has `n(n-1)/2` edges, it will give as `n(n-1)(n-2)` edges.

Answer (score 2):

Modify Bellman-Ford to keep track of two distances for each vertex: the minimum distance achievable via an even and an odd number of edges. In the update step (step 2 in the Wikipedia article) update distances with zero or actual weight as appropriate given the path length.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm